# Spring Cloud Config and caching

Tags: offline-caching, spring-cloud-config

I'm a Spring Boot beginner. I need to know if Spring Cloud Config supports a local cache system so that the central configuration, after being read by the server, is stored in a cache.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Spring Cloud Config caches configurations retrieved from Git. You can specify a folder in which configurations will be stored per repository using

```
spring.cloud.config.server.git.basedir
```

or

```
spring.cloud.config.server.svn.basedir
```

For more info see
https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/single/spring-cloud-config.html#_version_control_backend_filesystem_use